# Do I need to verify JWT token in PrivateRoutes component if I use redux and redux persist? (with local storage)

Tags: reactjs, authentication, jwt

I have a social media application. The token is being issued whenever user logs in (obviously).
Do I need to send the token to the backend to verify it before letting an access to Private Routes?

```
const PrivateRoutes = () => {
   let token = useSelector((state) => state.token);

   return(
     token ? <Outlet/> : <Navigate to="/auth/login" />
   )

}
```

If I in fact do need to verify the token, is the approach below correct? Is it ok to use local auth state here instead of the one that is in a redux store? (Sorry I am new to user authentication). Also, if user got through the token verification and got to the feed page, do I need to verify the token of the user when fetching for example all other users on "/people" page? Or would it be redundant since the token is checked  in PrivateRoutes component on every reload and I can get rid of "verifyJWT" in this route: router.get("/", verifyJWT, getAllUsers);
Thank you!

```
const PrivateRoutes = () => {
   const navigate = useNavigate();
   let token = useSelector((state) => state.token);
   const dispatch = useDispatch();

   const [auth, setAuth] = useState(false);
   const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);


   useEffect(() => {
      if(token) {
         const url = import.meta.env.VITE_API_URL + "auth/protected";

         axios.get(url, {headers: {Authorization: token}})
            .then(response => {
               if(response.status === 200){
                  setAuth(true);
               }
            })
            .then(() => {
               setIsLoading(false);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
               dispatch(setLogout()); //sets token and user states to null as well as authorized to false 
               //(authorized redux state is used to determine what kind of headr should be loaded)

               setAuth(false);
               setIsLoading(false);
               console.log(err)
            })
         
      }else{
         navigate("/auth/login");
      }
   }, [])


   if(isLoading) {
      return (
         <div>Loading</div>
      )
   }

   return(
     auth ? <Outlet/> : <Navigate to="/auth/login" />
   )

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You always want to verify if the token is valid (which means the user can be authorized to perform an action) when sending request to access a route that would need a user to be authenticated, which means you will always send it from the front and decode it in the back.

For a lot of requests you need to check if the user has the right to do something, like deleting a comment or a post for example.

As for the token being sent into each request, as you are using axios, you can preconfigure it so that the token is sent. It is done via request interceptors.

You set the interceptor once, either when the user logs in, either when he arrives on the page if you have stored your token in order to persist connection.

You can have a look here: https://axios-http.com/docs/interceptors